# JPA countBy on column mapped with @OneToMany

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to count items countaining a specific string in a @OneToMany Set<String> column.

To do so, in my `JpaRepository<User, String>` i can use `.size()` on the result of `List<User> findByCompanyIds(String companyId);`, it works like a charm.

But i was expecting to use `long countByCompanyIds(String companyId);` but it does not work and i get a queryException.

Do i have to make a custom query or am i doing it wrong with the count querydsl?

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "companyId",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
            indexes = {
                    @Index(name = "company_ids_index", columnList = "company_ids")
            }
    )
    @Column(name = "company_ids")
    private Set<String> companyIds;

    public User() {
        companyIds = new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

```java
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
    /* WORKS PERFECTLY */
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"companyIds"})
    List<User> findByCompanyIds(String companyId);

    /* DOES NOT WORK */
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"companyIds"})
    long countByCompanyIds(String companyId);

    /* DOES NOT WORK (was proposed Here by @Nick) */
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"companyIds"})
    long countByCompanyIdsContaining(String companyId);
}
```

Exception trace:

```
 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
 org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list 
 [FromElement{explicit,collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias1,role=com.test.User.companyIds,
 tableName={none},tableAlias=companyids1_,origin=user user0_,columns={,className=null}}] [select count(generatedAlias0) 
 from com.test.User as generatedAlias0 left join generatedAlias0.companyIds as generatedAlias1 where generatedAlias1=:param0]
```

Comment: Could you provide the concrete Exception? Is Company an attribute of user? Please also provide the corresponding classes.

Comment: @DanielRafaelWosch I have edited my question to provide them

Comment: @MaX what about my answer, have you tried it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the `countByCompanyIdsContaining` approach is that it treats the `companyIds` set as a single string, which doesn't work as expected. To achieve what you want you can use a JPQL query:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM User u WHERE :companyId MEMBER OF u.companyIds")
```

However, if you prefer not to use a custom query, an alternative solution is to introduce an `@Embeddable` value object for the company ID. By doing so, you also align with best practices and ensure a more organized representation of your data.

Here's what a value object for a company ID might look like:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompanyId implements Serializable {

    private String value;

    public CompanyId() {
        // Hibernate requires default constructor
    }

    public CompanyId(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // Getter, equals and hashCode methods
}
```

Next, update the `User` entity to use the `CompanyId` type and specify how the column should be mapped using `@AttributeOverride` annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "companyId",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
            indexes = {
                    @Index(name = "company_ids_index", columnList = "company_ids")
            }
    )
    @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "company_ids"))
    private Set<CompanyId> companyIds;

    public User() {
        companyIds = new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to use query like `long countByCompanyIdsContaining(CompanyId companyId)`

Comment: The problem is Company is not one of my entity, it's from another service somewhere else. The only entity I have is User. Since `List<User> findByCompanyIds(String companyId);` is working perfectly to find every entity with `companyId` value within this set of String I thought it would be easy to count them efficiently (without having to user `findByCompanyIds("foo").size()`). But it does not seem to be possible. 
I also tried some custom query as discussed below with Andrei but none of my attempts worked

Comment: @MaX It does not need to be an entity, I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: @MaX I also added the correct JPQL query to the answer

Comment: Thank you, indeed it seems to be the best way!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correct your query in Repository should look so:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(user) FROM User user LEFT JOIN u.companyIds cP WHERE cP IN :companyId")
Long findBySpecialtiesIn(Set<String> companyId);
```

And in your append of this method you will pass something like this

```
Collections.singleton(companyIds);
```

Comment: I would like not to use custom query, but maybe I have no other choice. Are you sur about `user.companyId = :companyId` ? I do not have a `companyId` but a set of string named "companyIds".

Comment: I think somethink like `@Query("SELECT COUNT(user) From User user where :companyId member user.companyIds")` should work

Comment: In the method as parameter you have a single one string and you need to do it how i wrote.

Comment: But you can try this two approach (your and my) and see wich one will work. P.S just tell me what was the right

Comment: I tried `@Query("SELECT COUNT(user) FROM User user WHERE user.companyId = ?1")` but it failed to deploy with Exception `EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; ...  could not resolve property: companyId of: com.test.User...`

Comment: I mean companyIds, becouse it is name of your field in User class `user.companyIds`

Comment: sir, any details ?

Comment: Just tried but it fails because type does not match : `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [e4c0d567-49cd-4290-b204-50d16d3058b3] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)];`
The query I proposed above does not work neither

Comment: what about my one ?

Comment: It failed with the exception I pasted.

Comment: I' m going to try this approach and will update my answer, i will let you know it.

Comment: @MaX i just updated my answer, try all these 3 approach, and give me a feedback if is was helpful and witch one have a positive impact in your case

Comment: None of them work in my case. For the first one exception is `QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=cP,role=com.test.User.companyIds,tableName={none},tableAlias=companyids1_,origin=user user0_,columns={,className=null}}]
`
Second and third got similar exception but with `classAlias=user`

Comment: for the first one change `JOIN` with `JOIN FETCH`

Comment: unfortunately I got the Same error with the "JOIN FETCH" version

Comment: give me some time, i will give you to know

Comment: i updated my answer, check this one more approach ))))

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and your time. Unfortunately it still does not work: `.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=cP,role=com.test.User.companyIds,tableName={none},tableAlias=companyids1_,origin=user user0_,columns={,className=null}}]`

Comment: [from here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile?originPath=%2Fbrowse%2FHHH-14113#issue/HHH-14113) you cand find something that can help you

Comment: Why don't you create a new entity `Company` ?  and after it will be more easy to extract list of users by companyId

Comment: The problem is Company is not one of my entity, it's from another service somewhere else. I could still create it I guess and make it work, but my question still need an answer.
Let's take another example : If I have just one entity called `Document` and this entity needs a list of tag. Then I would add to this entity a `Set<String> tags`, correct? Now I want to count how many `Document` contains the tag "foo", what is the best way to do that? It would not make sense to me to create a tag entity because it is literraly a String. Am I wrong?

Comment: so, if you have a entity with a field that is an `Set<String>`, how do you will store it in database as an `array` or `json/jsonb` ? but if you will have a entity `Tag` with some fields like(id, name) you can count it with `IN` or `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:
`long countByCompanyIdContaining(String companyId)`
I tested this in a local project and it works fine for your case, most likely the syntax was not entirely correct since you are looking for something containing a certain String.

Comment: Just tried `long countByCompanyIdsContaining(String companyId)` (with an 's') but it fails with exception `org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list ...`

Comment: This isn't related to the count, it's an issue with the relation between your entities. I can't tell you more w/o seeing it. Otherwise did you try it w/o the 's'? I'm not sure if this can have an affect, but when testing I didn't use an 's'.

Comment: Without  the 's' It cannot be deployed, exception : `.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name ... No property companyId found for type User! Did you mean 'companyIds'?`

Comment: I thought your company id is a single string field, if it's a set you can consider `countByCompanyIdsIn(String companyId)`. But I also think that your issue comes from the @ElementCollection or @CollectionTable annotation. From the exception it seems your company table doesn't exist or isn't found when you try to query it? It might have something to do with the eager fetching.

Comment: I think the "In" is for a collection as argument not for a column (Set\<String\>) you want to search in

Comment: I can confirm the "In" is for a collection as argument since it fails : `IllegalStateException: Operator IN on companyIds requires a Collection argument...`

Comment: Yeah good point, I'll try something else and tell you if it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this can't be achived with the countBy query. You need to use the custom query to fetch the data.
Do read this.
**https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2348**

Using a native query you can achive this

```
@Query(value = "Select count(*) from User u join company_id c on u.id = c.id AND c.company_ids = :companyId",nativeQuery = true)
int totalCountUserByCompanyId(@Param("companyId") String companyId);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late, this native query also works, thank you!